# What is the expected syntax for http_request put request?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, devops

I am using this `http_request` block in my cookbook:

```
http_request 'some request' do
  url 'https://'"#{node[:chef][:node_name]}"'/v1/xyz'
  headers ({
     'AUTHORIZATION' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64('#{node[\'user\']}:#{node[\'password\']')}",
    })
  action :get
end
```

However I get this error when I try to execute it:

```
[2017-05-12T21:39:04-04:00] ERROR: http_request[some request] (mi_activemq::default line 58) had an error: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL Error connecting to https://... - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed
```

If I hardcode the `username:password` this works as expected:

```
'AUTHORIZATION' => "Basic #{Base64.encode64('username:password')}",
```

Comment: See "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Please put more effort into your question.

Comment: Hope it is clear now

Comment: You seems​ to have a problem with openssl. make sure You are using at least 1.0.2 version and that this command 'openssl s_client -connect yourdomain:443 ' works . If the address You are connecting is www.example.com please replace yourdomain with example.com ( without www.)

Comment: NO it works if the username:password is hardcoded

Comment: The problem is `'#{node[\'user\']}:#{node[\'password\']'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to learn how to interpolate values into strings. Starting with this Hash definition:

```
node = {
  chef: {
    node_name: 'foo'
  }
}
```

And this string definition:

```
'https://'"#{node[:chef][:node_name]}"'/v1/xyz'
# => "https://foo/v1/xyz"
```

Ruby will concatenate adjacent strings into one string:

```
'foo'"bar"'baz' # => "foobarbaz"
```

but the code is ugly to read so don't do that unless you have a very good reason. Instead simply write it:

```
'foobarbaz' # => "foobarbaz"
```

or:

```
"foobarbaz" # => "foobarbaz"
```

Remember that the more confusing your code is, the harder it'll be for you, or someone else, to figure out what it means in six months.

So, instead of your string above, use:

```
"https://#{node[:chef][:node_name]}/v1/xyz"
# => "https://foo/v1/xyz"
```

You have another problem with your code:

```
require 'base64'
"Basic #{Base64.encode64('#{node[\'user\']}:#{node[\'password\']')}"
# > "Basic I3tub2RlWyd1c2VyJ119OiN7bm9kZVsncGFzc3dvcmQnXQ==\n"
```

This is the crux of the problem:

```
'#{node[\'user\']}:#{node[\'password\']'
# => "\#{node['user']}:\#{node['password']"
```

When the code runs, the value passed to `Base64.encode64` is that string. Your variables aren't being interpolated in so you'll always get:

```
# > "Basic I3tub2RlWyd1c2VyJ119OiN7bm9kZVsncGFzc3dvcmQnXQ==\n"
```

for the resulting string. It doesn't have your user or password encoded in it.

A potential second problem is that your `node` hash might not have `'user'` or `'password'` keys, but we can't tell because you didn't give us enough information.

A clearer and cleaner way to call `encode64` would be:

```
encoded_user_password = Base64.encode64(
  node.values_at('user', 'password').join(':')
)
```

then interpolate it into the string:

```
"Basic #{encoded_user_password}"
```

I'd recommend getting familiar with Ruby's [URI](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class also, as it's a preferred way of building and manipulating URIs.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated explanation Tin Man. It Works like a charm!
PS: Yes, I am new to ruby/chef got to catchup on lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess of various escape characters going on there, but the error is related to the name being wrong either in the cert or the URL.

Just put the user/pass in the URL,

```
url "https://#{node['user']}:#{node['password']@#{node['fqdn']}/v1/xyz"
```

where `node['fqdn']` is the name in the cert.